# Which products have a large E Ink Carta display?

Tags: displays, e-reader

The [E Ink Carta](http://www.eink.com/display_products_carta.html) is the electronic paper display used in the Amazon Kindle Voyage and latest generation Kindle Paperwhite ebook readers. It has 300ppi resolution, a very good contrast ratio and excellent readability even in direct sunlight.

The current Kindle lineup includes only readers with 6" displays, which many people find too small for comfortable reading. While larger ebook readers exist on the market (such as Amazon's own Kindle DX), none of them seem to have a display as good as the E Ink Carta in terms of resolution and contrast.

Interestingly, [the Carta product data sheet](http://www.eink.com/sell_sheets/carta_spec_sheet.pdf) states that sizes up to 13.3" are available from E Ink to manufacturers. Which end-user products contain those larger Carta displays? In particular, are there any ebook readers (current or planned) with a Carta display larger than 6"?

Comment: I have done considerable searching and so far 6" seems to be the limit manufacturers like. The only 13" screen I have found is a Mobius screen. These are all 6 inch: https://www.energysistem.com/en/products/ebook_reader/e-ink_series/42492-energy_ereader_pro_+ , http://www.banggood.com/Boyue-T62-8G-Dual-Core-6-Inch-WIFI-Android-Ebook-Reader-p-942029.html , http://onyx-boox.ru/boox_c67ml_darwin

Comment: This list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_readers#Electronic-paper_displays only has one 13 inch which is the Sony Mobius one

Comment: Kobos have up to 8.6": https://uk.kobobooks.com/products/kobo-aura-h2o

Answer (score 4):

**Update: May 2023**

In the intervening 8 years since my original answer I eventually did purchase a [Remarkable 2](https://remarkable.com/), which is a larger format note taking device that also functions as a capable e-reader (though it does have drawbacks like a lack of compatibility with Amazon Kindle books - you can workaround this, but it is annoying). I used to recommend this device without reservation, but it is somewhat dated now in terms of tech, and they have added what amounts to a mandatory subscription for basic syncing functionality etc. (as an early purchaser I get to keep the functionality without a sub).

In terms of current options, if I did not still own the Remarkable 2, I would be looking at the [Kindle Scribe](https://www.engadget.com/amazon-kindle-scribe-review-e-ink-reader-tablet-pen-drawing-price-battery-life-140019784.html), or the [Boox Tab Ultra C](https://goodereader.com/blog/reviews/review-of-the-onyx-boox-tab-ultra-c-kaleido-3-color-e-paper-tablet) which even has colour (at a lower PPI).

**Original Answer**

I have not pulled the trigger on this purchase, (because of the relatively high price), so this is not a hands-on recommendation.  When I went looking for an e-reader for reviewing and consuming technical information, I was most tempted by the [Icarus Excel](http://www.icarusreader.com/).

It is a 9.7" reader and allows for handwritten notes too.  Since I was evaluating for technical learning, this was a big plus.  The Icarus site is not great, but there is a good review, with video, [here](http://goodereader.com/blog/reviews/review-of-the-icarus-excel-9-7-inch-e-reader).

I don't think the market for these larger format readers is particularly mature, and [color e-ink](http://www.eink.com/display_products_triton.html) may yet disrupt the entire market (small format included).  If the larger format is a must have, and money is not an issue, then the Excel looks like a good option right now.

Comment: NB: [Icarus is no longer making e-readers and the company has disappeared](https://goodereader.com/blog/electronic-readers/icarus-is-no-longer-making-e-readers-and-the-company-has-disappeared)

Comment: added more recent info, as well as what I went with in the meantime

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the update. The forced subscription and the lack of a way to extend its storage (e.g. microSD) meant that this one was right off of the list of candidates.

Answer (score 0):

I own an InkPad Lite from PocketBook. It features a 9.7 inch (24.64 cm) E-Ink Carta™ display, so falls into the range you give. Of course it's quite a bit after you asked, but others may be interested in this still.

I don't use any of its online features of the InkPad Lite, except every once in a while checking for firmware updates. The firmware is Linux-based, but they don't give many details. It doesn't seem to be an Android, however. Most of the time I simply keep it in offline/airplane mode.

It has a backlight which can be adjusted to the surrounding lighting or manually adjusted. I keep it on most of the time and it doesn't affect battery life much.

The screen is touch sensitive and the usual gestures for flipping pages are fast enough for my taste, albeit probably not super fast.

Two other features that let me decide in favor of this device were the microSD slot and the fact that it uses a USB-C form factor socket.

PS: I can confirm that readability in sunlight or generally daylight is excellent.